# Which is the proper usage? "inure with" or "inure to"

Tags: word-usage

For example, given the sentence:

> She's learned to deal with solving difficult problems at an early age

If I wanted to rephrase this using the word "inure", which of the following is correct?

> She's learned to inure with solving difficult problems at an early age.

or

> She's learned to inure to solving difficult problems at an early age.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a locution I haven't heard. I'd say "She'd become inured to solving difficult problems at an early age."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Supporting your answer with sources makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise it appears to be only opinion. Please feel free to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: Thanks for answering Sean. This does appear to flow much better than the example sentences I provided.

Comment: Sean provided a good answer. Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

One becomes *inured to* unhappy, difficult, or otherwise troubling circumstances.  One does not become inured to *overcoming* them.